# Настройка подсветки синтаксиса пользовательских классов в XCode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Создал свой класс в *XCode 6* - наследник *UIView*.

Импортировал *UIKit*, тем не менее при написании кода не появляются подсказки для *UI*-классов, код не подсвечивается. При компиляции ошибок нет, в других классах подсказки есть.

С чем может быть связано?

Comment: попробуйте удалить derived data и сделать clean

Answer (score 1):

Такая проблема может появляться когда при создании нового класса выбран шаблон для Mac вместо iOS и создан Cocoa Class вместо Cocoa Touch Class.